# Is there a directive to individually import a Spring Integration gateway in Java configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In my Spring Boot application, I generally prefer to use `@Import` to individually activate my service beans instead of using `@ComponentScan`. I have an interface that's annotated with Spring Integration's `@MessagingGateway` and is intended to be used as an MQ entry point:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = CHANNEL_DISPATCH_QUEUE)
interface DispatchQueue {
  public static final String CHANNEL_DISPATCH_QUEUE = "dispatchQueue"

  void enqueue(Dispatch dispatch)
}
```

I tried to enable this in our usual style by adding `@Import(DispatchQueue)` to a configuration class, but I get an exception saying `Specified class is an interface`.

I'm aware that I could use `@IntegrationComponentScan` to turn on component scanning, but is there a mechanism equivalent to `int:gateway` that would allow me to tell Spring "activate this specific gateway interface" from Java configuration?

---

Note: An indirect solution using an `IntegrationFlow` will not work in my case because [gateways declared in `IntegrationFlow`s aren't visible to the Spring context before the flow is started](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3922); I need the typed bean in the context.

Answer (score 0):

The current solution is like this:

```
@Bean 
AnnotationGatewayProxyFactoryBean myGateway() {
    return new AnnotationGatewayProxyFactoryBean(MyGateway.class);
}
```

See its javadocs:

```
 * A {@link GatewayProxyFactoryBean} extension for Java configuration.
 * The service interface may be marked with the {@link MessagingGateway} annotation.
 * Otherwise, the default state is applied.
```

For the whole story there is also a GH issue to consider `@Import` support for interfaces: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3923 .
But I doubt it can done since an `@Import` is a part of Spring Framework which has no knowledge about Spring Integration gateway proxy infrastructure.

Comment: I'm aware of the `AnnotationGatewayProxyFactoryBean`, but since it isn't generic and otherwise doesn't expose the wrapped `MyGateway` type, I don't expect that the context will see this as a `MyGateway` implementation.

Comment: Right. I commented about that in the mention issue. I'll look into it next week. Thank you for your patience!